# Script for connecting to bluetooth device not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, services, bluetooth

I "copied" a bash script from a video that turns on my Bluetooth and connects to my Bluetooth headphones

```
#!/bin/bash 
systemctl enable bluetooth.service 
systemctl start bluetooth.service 
echo -e 'power on \nconnect MAC_Address \nquit' | bluetoothctl
```

When I just start my headphones and try to connect it to my pc using this script, it doesn't connect or just takes some time to connect (a good few seconds after the script is executed).

Or, sometimes I have to run the script again to connect.

But, sometimes, it just connects perfectly.

Is there an issue with my script?